# How to read Amazon SQS using spark

Tags: amazon-web-services, scala, apache-spark, pyspark

I am currently working on a project where I would like read an Amazon SQS queue from spark. I am using Java SDK to read from the Amazon SQS and then create dataframe out of it. I would like to know if there is any library which supports reading from SQS directly  from spark like we have for (kafka and kinesis)or I need to implement a custom receiver.

Comment: I am not clear what you mean by is there a library which supports reading from SQS directly. You stated that you are using the AWS SDK for Java to read an Amazon SQS queue. YOU are already using the API that lets you read an Amazon SQS queue in a Java environment.

Comment: @smac2020 I mean from spark is there any reader which directly read from sqs like we have for kafka or kinesis

Comment: There is no additional lib meant for Amazon SQS use within Apache Spark. However, Apache Spark does support JVM languages - which means you can use the AWS SDK for Java in that environment.

Comment: @smac2020 I can use it but then I need to put my extra logic to create dataframe out of it .For kafka spark ha something like below  spark
  .readStream
  .format("kafka")
  .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "host1:port1,host2:port2")
  .option("subscribe", "topic1")
  .load()
This support streaming from kafka .I wanted to know if i can directly stream from sqs where spark will act like consumer as above

Comment: Hi were you able to find any solution for this. I have the same use case